# Doxygen->Sphinx->Pygments code-blocks lexer choice?

Tags: doxygen, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, pygments

Esteemed colleagues!

We've a large C++ project, with documentation created with Doxygen->Sphinx->Pygments.  99% of it works great, since we're documenting C++ code in *.cc files.

However, there are some *.cc files that attempt to create code-blocks for OTHER LANGUAGES.  I'm having trouble passing the lexer choice down to Pygments so it can highlight correctly.

Here's my approach within a file, lets call "stackoverflow.cc".  These all "work" as I expect:

`````
``` shell
%> This is correctly highlighted as a shell script.
%> Perhaps because Doxygen understands it naitvely?
```

``` c++
class StackOverflow : public Works {
  // This is correctly highlighted as C++.  Natively?
}
````

``` verbatim
class StackOverflow : public Works {
  // This is *ALSO* correctly highlighted as C++.
  //
  // I presume that BECAUSE the file extension is *.cc
  //   that Sphinx(?) selects the C++ lexer.
  //
  // My other presumption is that the "verbatim" block
  //   causes the contents to be passed unmodified from
  //   Doxygen down to Sphinx where it can process
  //   reStructuredText.  No?
}
```
`````

I expect that this block below will choose a different lexer, and emit different highlighting, but it doesn't.  It's still highlighted as C++.  The reStructuredText, such as the ".. code-blocks:: basemake" directive are emitted and highlighted just like the other text in this block!

````
``` verbatim

  .. code-block:: basemake

      FOO := $(filter foo,${SOME_VAR})

      target: dependencies
        recipe $(FOO)

  ..

```
````

Where am I making a mistake?
How can I get that block to be highlighted as if it was a Makefile format instead of C++?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about Doxygen. Try other lexers http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#lexers-for-makefiles-and-similar Also make sure your reST syntax is correctly indented and spaced.

Comment: A blank line is needed after `.. code-block:: basemake`  and the content of the code-block should be indented. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-code-block

Comment: @mzjn:   My block is indented four spaces, and I've added the blank line (Thanks!) but I still don't get the output. My reST is still emitted as if it's part of the code block.  Choosing a different lexer doesn't make a difference. Hmm...

Comment: The *content* of the block (the make rules in this case) must be indented related to `.. code-block:: basemake`.

Comment: @mzjn:  I'd love to give you an , but I've tried all sorts of indenting and blank lines on simple code and it still just puts the ".. code-block:: basemake" into the document.  I've got Sphinx 1.8.1 and Pygments 2.2.0 (and Python 3.6.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found the following seemed to work,

```
/*!
\verbatim embed:rst
.. code-block:: basemake

  FOO := $(filter foo,${SOME_VAR})

  target: dependencies
  recipe $(FOO)

\endverbatim
*/
```

which is then highlighted as `reStructuredText` as expected. Note it required a comment block with an exclaimation after `/*!` to `*/`